# Running lpr through command line and through python different outcome

Tags: python, printing, cups, lpr

When I run `lpr <filename>.jpg` the file prints out boderless (this is what I want).

When I run `subprocess.call("/usr/bin/lpr " + tmp.name, shell=True)` from a Python program, it prints out with borders.

Output from `lpoptions` shows the below (`StpBorderless=True`, and `StpiShrinkOutput=Expand` should make it borderless I think).

How can I execute `lpr` from a Python script to use the exact same options as if I executed it from command line?

```
auth-info-required=none
copies=1
device-uri=usb://Canon/CP800?serial=DH00071100000840
finishings=3
job-hold-until=no-hold
job-priority=50
job-sheets=none,none
marker-change-time=0
number-up=1
printer-commands=none
printer-info='Canon CP800'
printer-is-accepting-jobs=true
printer-is-shared=false
printer-location printer-make-and-model='Canon SELPHY-CP770 - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.9'
printer-state=3
printer-state-change-time=1433298534
printer-state-reasons=none printer-type=2134028
printer-uri-supported=ipp://localhost:631/printers/Canon_CP800
StpBorderless=True
StpiShrinkOutput=Expand
```

Comment: Why are using `subprocess.call` with `shell=True`?

Comment: I thought using shell=True would make it behave more similar to running it from within the shell manually.

Comment: Differences like that are often the result of differences in the environment variables. There may be program specific variables, or the program may be looking for config files in folders or search paths defines in an environment variable.